# Use Firefox add-on SDK to construct a web page

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to build an Firefox extension which after users click it, a web page is dynamically constructed and opened in a new tab.

In "tab" API, I only saw tab.open() open a hyperlink to a remote website. Can I construct a JavaScript variable contains all the HTML contents (Like var page = "blahblah....") and open it? How to do that?

Comment: You don't have to dynamically construct it, just put a htm page in your addon and then the link to it will be `resource://your addon id/blah.htm`. This addon here creates a page: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/twitch-alarm/

Comment: You can also create an about:blah url to your page, this shows how to do it without the sdk: https://github.com/Noitidart/ZooniverseXpert

Comment: Noitidart, your comment is the correct answer. Not sure why you choose to leave it as a comment

Comment: @Noitidart That helps, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to dynamically construct it, just put a htm page in your addon and then the link to it will be resource://your addon id/blah.htm. This addon here creates a page: addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/twitch-alarm

You can also create an about:blah url to your page, this shows how to do it without the sdk: github.com/Noitidart/ZooniverseXpert

Comment: do you understand the difference between a static page and a dynamic page?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a html page dynamically but put a html page in your addon and refer it when you open a tab.

```
tabs.open({
    url : self.data.url("js/error.html"),
    onReady : function(tab) {
        var errorWorker = tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile : self.data.url("js/error.js")
        });
        errorWorker.port.emit("error_page",message);
    }
});
```

Here I am displaying an error page which is stored in my addon and attaching a content script file to dynamically change the contents of html page through message passing between main.js and error page.
Hope it is of some use to you.